# Replace All `[ ]` character from the string

Tags: java, regex

I have a String.

```
 String myStrangeString = "java-1.7, ant-1.6.5, sonar-runner], [java-1.7, ant-1.6.5, sonar-runner], [java-1.7, ant-1.6.5, sonar-runner";
```

I want to remove all the `[]` characters from the `myStrangeString`.

I tried,

```
myStrangeString.replaceAll("[[]]", "")
```

but got error as

```
Return Value :Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 3
[[]]
   ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2493)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2030)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1337)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2162)
    at Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

what can i do to remove the `[]` from my `myStrangeString`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape those inner brackets. `[` and `]` are special meta characters in regex which means the start and end of a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). So to match a literal `[`, `]` symbols, you must need to escape that.

```
myStrangeString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "")
```

Example:

```
String myStrangeString = "java-1.7, ant-1.6.5, sonar-runner], [java-1.7, ant-1.6.5, sonar-runner], [java-1.7, ant-1.6.5, sonar-runner";
System.out.println(myStrangeString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));
```

Output:

```
java-1.7, ant-1.6.5, sonar-runner, java-1.7, ant-1.6.5, sonar-runner, java-1.7, ant-1.6.5, sonar-runner
```

Answer (score 0):

i think is the answer you are looking for is

```
myStrangeString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
```

but if your string is not big and performance is not an issue you can do it in two steps... remove all [ and then remove all ]

```
 myStrangeString.replace("[", "");
 myStrangeString.replace("]", "");
```

Comment: I was initially doing the same two step workaround, but was not felling good about the code. :-)